# Access the numbers only in output value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

My script gives me energy output as:

```
E = [0.0432929 kcal mol-1 ]
```

`E[:1]` also gives me same.

On multiplication with 2 gave me:

`[0.0432929 kcal mol-1, 0.0432929 kcal mol-1]` while `Len` function gives me `1` value for `E`.

Could anyone please tell me how I can access to numerical value only? Thanks.

Comment: E[0].split(" ")[0] ?

Comment: not working, 'GeneralUnit' object has no attribute 'split' got this error.

Comment: What do you get when you do `print(repr(E))`?

Answer (score 1):

If what you have is a string (E[0])

```
"0.0432929 kcal mol-1"
```

You should split the words and then transform the first in a number:

```
x = E[0].split()
x = float(x[0])
```

now x is the number you want.

Comment: it gives me the error ;
'GeneralUnit' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: So your 'E[0]' ins't really a string. You should see how this GeneralUnit object works, it may have a method that gives you its numerical value. Try printing dir(E[0]) or help(E[0])

Comment: it is program output. I am using other program library to calculate energy. I try with this.

Comment: dir gives me this; 
['ANGLE', 'CHARGE', 'LENGTH', 'MASS', 'QUANTITY', 'TEMPERATURE', 'TIME', '__add__', '__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__idiv__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__instance_size__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rlshift__', '__rmul__', '__rrshift__', '__rtruediv__', '__setattr__',  .......]

Comment: try y = str(E[0]) and then what's in my answer using y.

Comment: y = str(E[0]) 
print(len(y))
x = y.split()
print(x)
print(x[0])

Comment: but on multiplication or on any operation it is still same.

Comment: i got 2*x[0] = -0.0218656-0.0218656

Comment: Did you cast to float? x = float(x[0])

Comment: Do you know any good book on python ? sorry for irrelevant question.

Comment: beginner (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596158071.do) and intermediaate (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596158118.do)